# Kdevelop and ROS, how can I use a launch file to luanch a ROS node in Kdevelop?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone help me ? thank you first

I want to use kdevelop to debug ROS C++ program, but I do not know how can I use a use a launch file to luanch a ROS node in Kdevelop.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280665/kdevelop-and-ros,-how-can-i-use-a-launch-file-to-luanch-a-ros-node-in-kdevelop?/) by [lijianglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/33409/lijianglong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen [wiki/IDEs - kDevelop](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#kDevelop)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0